# Are there any restaurants landside at Gatwick airport? (Ideally North terminal)

Tags: airports, food-and-drink, london, lgw

I've got a very early flight out of London Gatwick coming up, so I've booked into a hotel that's very close to the North terminal, to make the early start slightly less painful. I've just discovered that there isn't a restaurant at this hotel though, only breakfast, so I can't eat there when I arrive the night before.

Ideally, given the early start, I don't want to go too far to eat. What would be good is to find a restaurant (or similar) landside at the airport, which I can walk to / walk + shuttle ride to, to eat before I get an early night.

I know there are a fair number of restaurants airside at Gatwick, but I don't know about landside as I'm normally just dashing through that bit! I tried the [Gatwick airport restaurants directory](http://www.gatwickairport.com/at-the-airport/shopping-eating/restaurant-directory/), but that had no option to show only landside airports, which is pesky and possibly a bad sign...

That leads to the question - are there any restaurants / similar places to eat, landside at Gatwick, ideally in the North terminal, open until at least 9pm?

Comment: As alternative: Pizza, fish & chips, indian will all deliver to your hotel. Ask for brochures at check in time.

Answer (score 5):

Google Maps appears to show a Jamie's Italian and a seafood place called Caviar House & Prunier landside.

If you look carefully at the directory you'll see that there are two Jamie's Italians: [a "van" landside](http://www.gatwickairport.com/at-the-airport/shopping-eating/restaurants/jamies-van/) and [a restaurant airside](http://www.gatwickairport.com/at-the-airport/shopping-eating/restaurants/jamie-oliver/). (In the right column, under *Location*, it says *Before security* or *After security*). The seafood place, however, claims to be airside, so maybe Google has the location wrong. There's also a [Costa](http://www.gatwickairport.com/at-the-airport/shopping-eating/restaurants/costa/) (at least, I think "arrivals" means landside rather than next to the baggage collection), where you can probably get a soup and a ciabatta.

At the South Terminal, there's an [Apostrophe](http://www.gatwickairport.com/at-the-airport/shopping-eating/restaurants/apostrophe/), a [Nero](http://www.gatwickairport.com/at-the-airport/shopping-eating/restaurants/caffe-nero/), a [Giraffe](http://www.gatwickairport.com/at-the-airport/shopping-eating/restaurants/giraffe/), and a [Wetherspoons](http://www.gatwickairport.com/at-the-airport/shopping-eating/restaurants/the-beehive/) landside, although the latter two close too early for you.

Comment: Unless someone can confirm "Arrivals" is landside this won't work.

Comment: @chx, huh? The only one which gives its location as "Arrivals" is Costa.

Comment: Ah! The van is the solution, nice find.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.gatwickairport.com/at-the-airport/shopping-eating/shops/marks-and-spencer/

North

LOCATION: Before security
OPEN: 24 hours

Comment: That's not a restaurant though - M&S Simply Food is a (posh) supermarket

Comment: If the goal is not to starve a sandwich or salad will do.